# Can you force a string to split into 'n' lines?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

On a website I'm designing, I have a page with rows of categories thumbnails and their titles.

The problem is : some category titles are long, other are shorts... depending on the monitor width some will take 2 lines of text, or even 3, but not the others, creating ugly staircases.

I've managed to identify the highest title and min-height every other one accordingly with javascript.

But, it's still ugly. To make it better, I'd want every title to break into as many lines than the longest one.

That's where I come short... I couldn't find a way to do that so far.

**Here's how it is now :**

[image]

**Here's the intended result :**

[image]

Any idea how I could accomplish this ?

Comment: There's overflow, text-overflow, white-space and text-align you can use within CSS for the title's div. So for instance text-align:center; white-space:break-spaces;text-over-flow:ellipsis; over-flow:hidden;

Comment: Please show the (representative) "*[mcve]*" code you're using, that way we can offer practical, targeted solutions that are of specific use to your needs and from which others can learn in future.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that with a javascript solution you can count characters or words and add `<br>` after `n` amount. Here is a sample that will add a line break after every 20 characters:

```
var string = document.getElementById('text');
string.innerHTML = string.textContent.replace(/(.{20})/g, "$1<be>");
```

Then you can create a function with a loop for each element and do some if statement logic there. For example - add a break if the character count is more than...